# Can anyone tell me what is this sequence: 4, 14,23, 34, 42,50,59,66, 72,79,86, 96,103,110,116,125

Tags: sequences-and-series

4, 14, 23, 34, 42, 50, 59, 66, 72, 79, 86, 96,103,110,116,125

I googled it and everywhere this question is asked but without answer.

--

added:

this sequence comes from:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/readings/l12_skiplists.pdf

first page

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000054

Comment: It's not in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C+14%2C+23%2C+34%2C+42%2C+50%2C+59%2C+66%2C+72%2C+79%2C+86%2C+96%2C103%2C110%2C116%2C125&language=english&go=Search) (which says a lot). Edit: Ah, add an 81 and you get Byron's comment.

Comment: Maybe 81 is no longer in service. We need a Manhattaner to comment.

Comment: seems to be a typo, 81 is ok http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/81st_Street_%E2%80%93_Museum_of_Natural_History_(IND_Eighth_Avenue_Line)

Comment: There are uncountably many infinite sequences that start with those numbers.

Comment: Actually, 66 and 79 are missing in A000054.

Comment: In light of the answer, I really should vote to close as "off topic", but I just can't bring myself to do it...

Comment: The source PDF file has a really big clue: "Boxed values are “express” stops; others are normal stops."

Answer (score 3):

Except for the 4 at the beginning, the other numbers are the stops on the Number 1 subway line in New York City. If one started at the Courant Institute and wanted to go to Columbia University, and walked (it would take about 20 minutes) over to the Christopher St. stop - about 7th St., these are the stops that the train would make. (Courant is at 3rd St. and Mercer.)

Comment: Except that 28 St is missing.  Perhaps one should take the A train from W 4 St and change to the 1 at 59 St / Columbus Circle.  I think the stops on that route match the given sequence exactly.  For reference: http://www.mta.info/nyct/maps/submap.htm